# How to create a "memory" using an array of messages (Open AI API)

Tags: python, openai-api

I'm creating a friendly computer voice assistant that has access to Chat GPT, but whenever I ask it something, it has no recollection of anything I've asked it before. I realise that I need to add to the array **messages**, but I currently create a new one each time.
So I need to save all the previous questions and answers into this array and feed it back to Chat GPT whenever I speak to it.

My current code for interacting with Chat GPT is as follows:

```py
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
                        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
                        messages=[
                            {"role": "system", "content": "You are a sarcastic and helpful assistant. Answer as concisely as possible. Do refer to yourself as an AI or virtual assistant."},
                            {"role": "user", "content": statement}
                        ],
                        temperature=0.7
             )
answer = completion.choices[0].message.content
print(colors.GREEN + "CHAT GPT 3.5 >>>", answer + colors.ENDC)
speak(answer)
```

The **statement** comes from a Speech to text engine.

**speak** is a function which uses PicoTTS to make the computer speak back to me.

How, in Python, can I capture all the **statements** and **answers** into an array which should probably be called from a file where the conversation can be stored so my computer "remembers" our previous conversations?

Comment: The approach you took is wrong overall. You should rather create vector-embeddings of the parent data, store it in a vector-db. Then create embedding of a user's query, find the most relevant results and ask OpenAI's `completion` API to summarise it, which you can then use as an answer. As for memory, you take the same approach, only this time, replace the `parent_data` with your existing conversation.

Comment: If you want effective memory management and you don't want to roll your own solution from scratch (not trivial), I recommend using [LangChain's memory modules](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/).

Answer (score 0):

You should append to the messages object all the events of the conversation:

For example, to append user interaction:

```
messages.append({"role": "user", "content": message})
```

To append context for your voice assistant, like instructions, use:

```
messages.append({"role": "system","content":"You shoul be very friendly."})
```

To append functions for "function calling" use:

```
messages.append(
    {
        "role": "function",
        "name": function_name,
        "content": function_response,
    }
)
```

Then send the whole messages object, and that way it will have the full accumulated context.